# multiple charging with stripe and laravel

Tags: laravel, queue, stripe-payments

I am trying to charge the customer with stripe first time as a deposit and the second time is after 5 minutes which is the rest of the amount and this is handled by Laravel Queue.But for some reason the second charge is not happening

This is my controller

```
public function StripeCharge(Request $request) {

        $product_name = $request->product_name;
        $product_price = $request->product_price;

 

    Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
            "email" => $email = Auth::user()->email,
            "source" => $request->stripeToken
        ));

        $mailInfo = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
             "amount" => $product_price * 100,
             "currency" => "gbp",
             "customer" => $customer->id,
             "description" => "Deposit" . "-" . $product_name 
        ));

        $customerId = $customer->id;
        $amount = $product_price;


             
  
        $email = Auth::user()->email;
            
          Mail::to($email)->send(new WelcomeMail($mailInfo));

        
        $fullamount =  New ChargeCustomer($customerId,$amount); 


          dispatch(New ChargeCustomer( $fullamount) )->delay(now()->addMinutes(5));
        

        
          
        return view('confirmation');

    }
```

This is my job CustomerCharge

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Stripe;

class ChargeCustomer implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $customerId;
    public $amount;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(string $customerId, int $amount)
    {
       $this->customerId = $customerId;
       $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        \Stripe\Charge::create([
            'amount' => $this->amount,
            'currency'=> 'gbp',
            'customer' => $this->customerId

        ]);

        ChargeCustomer::dispatch('cus_test',1000);
    }
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is you're not specifying the Customer when you dispatch the second payment:

```php
New ChargeCustomer( $fullamount)
```

That should be something like `New ChargeCustomer($customerId, $fullamount)`, I believe.

However, at a higher level, creating two Charges one right after the other this way is not recommended.  Two separate Charges will incur double the fees vs. using one, and will look unusual to cardholders when they look at their statements.

If you want to make sure your customers can and will pay before actually taking their money you can place a hold on a card.  Doing so guarantees the funds are available, reserves them for you to capture later, and only uses a single Charge.

Here's Stripe's documentation for placing a hold on a card using the older Charges API you're currently using: https://stripe.com/docs/charges/placing-a-hold

Here's Stripe's newer documentation on the updated Payment Intents API they recommend you use instead: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later

Comment: Hi there thanks for your resposne. I make the changes and I am passing the customer id now but the queue is failing tue to following reason reason: No API key provided.  (HINT: set your API key using "Stripe::setApiKey(<API-KEY>)".  You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface.  See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm not sure how Laravel's dispatch queues work, but it's entirely possible those queues are using an entirely separate instance of Stripe than the one you initialized with your API key when creating the queued job.  You may need to initialize Stripe with your key inside the job itself.

Comment: @DonchoBorisov You may add the string `Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));` to the [ServiceProvider](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/providers). That's how you'll distribute the API key to all modules of the system. Controllers and CLI modules (queue workers in your case) are different entry points, and they know nothing about each other.